# How to insert records for next 6 days (Sun-Fri) when just date for (Sat) is given

Tags: sql, oracle

I have got truck capacity for 1 day in a week and same truck will be used throughout the week so I want to populate Capacity values on daily basis. i.e. I want to convert weekly data into daily data by populating same capacity value in SQL query

Below is data sample

```
Date                 capacity
6-Jan-2018      5.58
13-Jan-2018     4.6
```

Expected Result:

```
Date                capacity
 6-Jan-2018    5.58
 7-Jan-2018    5.58
 8-Jan-2018    5.58
 9-Jan-2018    5.58
 10-Jan-2018   5.58
 11-Jan-2018   5.58
 12-Jan-2018   5.58
13-Jan-2018    4.6
14-Jan-2018    4.6
15-Jan-2018    4.6
16-Jan-2018    4.6
17-Jan-2018    4.6
18-Jan-2018    4.6
19-Jan-2018    4.6
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? please add a minimal working code with error.

Answer (score 1):

Used following points (understanding) to give you a solution.

1. From your tag 'Oracle', I assume you need a solution for Oracle database
2. Your description **I have got truck capacity for 1 day in a week** and example suggest you will know the capacity right on the first day and that will be the capacity for all 7 days (current + next six days)

```
WITH VW_DWC AS (SELECT LEVEL-1 DAY_COUNT FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 7)
SELECT DT.DT_START + V.DAY_COUNT ON_DATE, DT.CAPACITY
FROM VW_DWC V CROSS JOIN ( 
  -- you can provide all your date, capacity pairs here as union all   
  SELECT to_date('06-Jan-2018', 'DD-MON-YYYY') DT_START, 5.58 AS CAPACITY from dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT to_date('13-Jan-2018', 'DD-MON-YYYY') DT_START, 4.6 AS CAPACITY from dual
) DT
ORDER BY ON_DATE
```

and the result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I presume you have a column to indicate the week number for each date for the start of week you have. Let's call it `week_no`. You may then use a simple `connect by` query with a standard `prior sys_guid` option( to prevent cycles)

```
select t.dt+ level-1 as dt, t.capacity 
  from t connect by level <= 7
    and prior week_no = week_no
and prior sys_guid() is not null;
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ad0ee9b7db431bf2aecd1f1142f77179)